# Why does mongostat show a non-existent database (Mongo 2.2)?

Tags: mongodb

when we run the `show dbs` command, the `x-development` database doesn't appear.

```
> show dbs
admin   (empty)
local   0.203125GB
p-development     0.203125GB
p-production      3.9521484375GB
test    (empty)
>
```

we want to make sure this database isn't taking server resources, but `mongostat` keeps listing it. why does this happen if the database doesn't exist?

```
[root@mongo]# mongostat
connected to: 127.0.0.1
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults               locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time
     0      5      0      0       0       1       1  2.11g  4.86g   464m      0 x-development:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0    62b     2k     3   11:42:57
     0      0      0      0       0       1       0  2.11g  4.86g   464m      0 x-development:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0    62b     2k     3   11:42:58
     0      0      0      0       0       1       0  2.11g  4.86g   464m      0 x-development:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0    62b     2k     3   11:42:59
```

Answer (score 0):

It don't think it's strange or wrong that mongo chooses to retain statistics of a deleted database. After all they are statistics.

Deleting the database does not change the fact that you ran queries against it before.

Comment: sorry, but it has not existed for many months ... that's the problem.

Comment: The somewhat odd thing is that it keeps showing 1 command per second against the deleted database. `mongostat` sends commands to get status, but how does it even know that it used to exist?

Comment: @Crashalot Are you sure you have no application code etc going to the db? Most specifically commands

Comment: Is not that mongostat itself? I mean the 1 command which running.

Comment: yes, we ran grep against our app code, and didn't find anything. there is a backup of this database in the mongo directory, however. does that matter?

Comment: @attish : you are correct, the 1 command is for the entire mongod process which is made from mongostat, not per database. This we can easily verify by running 1 more mongostat command which will make the 'command' count to 2 per sec

Comment: just restart mongod - some of these stats are kept in memory, this will ... refresh them.